# My domain only works with https://www.domainname.com otherwise domainname.com and www.domainname.com not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssl, apache2

My domain only works with https://www.domainname.com otherwise domainname.com and www.domainname.com not working
domain managed by godaddy and hosted on ubuntu and sslcert installed.

Pls suggest.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using an Apache server like your tags suggest, you should be able to add ServerAlias commands within your .conf file like so:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  ServerAdmin you@domainname.com
  DocumentRoot /opt/www/htdocs/domainname_com

  ServerName www.domainname.com
  ServerAlias domainname.com
</VirtualHost>
```

I highly suggest expanding and improving your question to get more detailed answers.